# unable to delete event on google calendar using ics file

Tags: icalendar

i create event on google calendar using ics file successfully but when i'm trying to  delete/cancel this event using ics file its not working.

---Create Ics----

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
METHOD:REQUEST
PRODID:-//ClaryIcon/NONSGML OneScreen//EN
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART:20180222T145000Z
DTEND:20180222T145000Z
SUMMARY:testttt
DESCRIPTION:Meeting Invite from OneScreen Hype\nMeeting Owner: ali\nSip Address: Not Supported\nDail in: \n\n
UID:5a8d8747eebadc109c908e11
DTSTAMP:20180221T145048Z
ORGANIZER;CN=ali:mailto:noreply-hype@onescreensolutions.com
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

---Cancel Ics----

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
METHOD:CANCEL
PRODID:-//ClaryIcon/NONSGML OneScreen//EN
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART:20180221T145152Z
DTEND:20180221T145152Z
SUMMARY:testttt
DESCRIPTION:
UID:5a8d8747eebadc109c908e11
DTSTAMP:20180221T145152Z
ORGANIZER;CN=ali:mailto:noreply-hype@onescreensolutions.com
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

mainly i use uid to identity specific event

Answer (score 0):

Try adding status:cancelled as per the RFC5545 spec

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#page-93

Not sure but you may also need a SEQUENCE (check spec for exact syntax ) to indicate which is latest modification.